# (C++) Read username and password from a file output problem

Tags: c++, registration

my program of registration and login encountered a few problems during output :

1. I have to register a new user and pass first(even if i alrd have previous usernames and passwords stored in the text file im trying to retrieve it from), after that only i can login using previous username and passwords and this repeats after i close the debug window and start debugging again    (if i directly choose to login upon running the program, it will output "invalid username or password")
2. when logging out from a newly registered username, the program jumps to the
   int main() AND DISPLAY "1. Register...."
   but logging out from previous usernames, it jumps to
   void login() and display "Username:"

*note: the last function isn't complete yet but i think it doesn't affect it (?) (the program worked fine before i added the `void accountPage()`tho)
*i am not supposed to use pointers plus i'm very new to c++

the code is a bit long but its just a lot of simple functions, i would rly appreciate it if someone can point out my mistake anywhere

````
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Global Variables
int Choice1;
int mobile, ic;
string user, pass, name, inUser, inPass;

//Function Prototypes
void register_user();
void login();
void bookRoom();
bool CheckCredentials(string, string);
void accountPage();

int main() 
{


    cout << "Welcome to Cozy Homes!\n";
    cout << "Operating hours: 11am - 10pm Tuesday - Sunday\n\n\n\n";

    do {
        cout << "\n1. Register\n";
        cout << "2. Log In\n";
        cout << "3. Exit\n";
        cout << "Please enter a number:";
        cin >> Choice1;

        if (Choice1 == 1)
        {
            register_user(); 
        }

        else if (Choice1 == 2)
        {
            login();
        }

        else if (Choice1 == 3)
        {
            cout << "Exiting now...\n";
            return 0;
        }

        else if (Choice1 < 1 || Choice1 > 3)
        {
            cout << "Please choose a number from the menu!" << endl;
        }

    } while (Choice1 != 3);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Register page
    void register_user()
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\n\n\n" << "New Username: ";
        getline(cin, user);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "New Password: ";
        getline(cin, pass);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Full name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Mobile Number: ";
        cin >> mobile;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Ic Number (without \" - \"): ";
        cin >> ic;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Registered Successfully!" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        //Store username and password in login file
        ofstream l("login.txt", ios::app);
        if (!l.is_open()) {
            cout << "could not open file \n";
        }


        l << user << " " << pass << endl;
        l << endl;
        l.close();

        //Store other details in customer file
        ofstream c("customer.txt", ios::app);
        if (!c.is_open()) {
            cout << "could not open file \n";
        }

        c << user << endl;
        c << pass << endl;
        c << name << endl;
        c << mobile << endl;
        c <<  ic << endl;
        c << '\n';
    
        c.close();

    }

    //Log in page
    void login() 
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "\nUsername: ";
            cin >> inUser;
            cout << "Password: ";
            cin >> inPass;


            if (CheckCredentials(inUser, inPass) == true)
            {
                cout << "\nLogin sucessful!" << endl;
                cout << "Welcome, " << inUser << endl;
                cout << endl;
                accountPage(); // Redirects user to their account page after successfully logged in
            }
            else
            cout << "\nInvalid username or password. " << endl;

        } while (CheckCredentials(inUser, inPass) != true);
    }
    
    //Validate their username and password
    bool CheckCredentials(string inUser, string inPass)
    {
        string u;
        string p;

        bool status = false;

        ifstream f;
        f.open("login.txt");

        if (!f.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Unable to open file!\n";
        }
        else if (f)
        {
            while (!f.eof())
            {
                f >> u >> p;
                if (inUser == u && inPass == p)
                {
                    status = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    status = false;
                }
            }
        }

        f.close();
        return status;
    }
    
    //Account Page
    void accountPage()
    {
        int Choice2;

        do
        {
            cout << "1. Profile\n";
            cout << "2. Book a Room\n";
            cout << "3. Cancel Booking\n";
            cout << "4. Logout\n";

            cout << "Please enter a number: ";
            cin >> Choice2;

            if (Choice2 == 1)
            {

            }
            else if (Choice2 == 2)
            {
                
            }
            else if (Choice2 == 3)
            {

            }
            else if (Choice2 == 4)
            {
                cout << "Logging out.....\n\n\n\n";
                cout << endl;
            }
        } while (Choice2 != 4);
    }

    //Booking page
    void bookRoom() {
        cout << " ";
    }
        ```
````

Comment: what is ommitted in the register function ? You don't have a value for user and pass yet when you write to the file. I must say, weird excercise

Comment: @PhilipStuyck is the omit still there? i edited the code now, can you see the added code?

Comment: in the loop the first while loop is wrong. At that point if you start with a new program, inuser and inpass is empty. You need a do while loop.

Comment: ```do
  {
   cout << "\nUsername: ";
   cin >> inUser;
   cout << "Password: ";
   cin >> inPass;


   if (CheckCredentials(inUser, inPass) == true)
   {
    cout << "\nLogin sucessful!" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome, " << inUser << endl;
    cout << endl;
    accountPage(); // Redirects user to their account page after successfully logged in
   }
   else
   cout << "\nInvalid username or password. " << endl;

  } while (CheckCredentials(inUser, inPass) != true);```
like this?  cos i tried this but i encountered the same problems

Comment: I am not going to read that. But still wrong

Comment: How are you planing on dealing with names or passwords containing spaces? If the file contains `John Doe password`, is the username `John Doe` and the password `password` or the user name `John` and the password `Doe password`? Btw: do yourself a favor and create classes/structs and preferably avoid global vars; this makes keeping related data together much easier

Comment: this is just a school excercise,fabian. One problem at a time

Comment: @fabian speaking of structs, is it possible to modify the struct members later on in the code? ie. when the user wants to book a room and i would want to add their booking details to their struct (preferably in a function). or should i create another struct for the booking details?

Comment: @Carolyn This kind of info has a different lifecycle. A reasonable OOA would yield seperate entity types `Person` and `Booking`. You may want to store the booking info in the person object itself, e.g. by adding a `std::vector<Booking> m_bookings;` field for in the `Person` object or store the info in a completely "external" structure. This entirely depends on how you want to use the data.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
void login() 
{
    bool loggedin = false;
    while(!loggedin)
    {
        cout << "\nUsername: ";
        cin >> inUser;
        cout << "Password: ";
        cin >> inPass;


        if (CheckCredentials(inUser, inPass) == true)
        {
            loggedin = true;
            cout << "\nLogin sucessful!" << endl;
            cout << "Welcome, " << inUser << endl;
            cout << endl;
            accountPage(); // Redirects user to their account page after successfully logged in
        }
        else
        cout << "\nInvalid username or password. " << endl;

    } 
}
```

or like this:

```
void login() 
{
    bool loggedin = false;
    do 
    {
        cout << "\nUsername: ";
        cin >> inUser;
        cout << "Password: ";
        cin >> inPass;


        if (CheckCredentials(inUser, inPass) == true)
        {
            loggedin = true;
            cout << "\nLogin sucessful!" << endl;
            cout << "Welcome, " << inUser << endl;
            cout << endl;
            accountPage(); // Redirects user to their account page after successfully logged in
        }
        else
        cout << "\nInvalid username or password. " << endl;

    } 
    while(!loggedin)
}
```

As this is a school assignment I did not bother to test the code myself.
It is just meant to get you futher and I did only minimal changes.
The point of your error is that the faulty function calls checkcredentials before a user and pasword is entered in the system.
If this solves your problem please mark as solution.

```
    l << user << " " << pass << endl;
    l << endl; <---- creates an empty line in your file. Is this intentional ?
    l.close();
```

Clearly there is more bugs in your program. But this will get you further.
Have to do my own job now ;-)

Comment: I tried this and only the last username & password can be read and validated. is there smtg wrong with my ```void CheckCredentials()``` ?

Comment: looks like it. I think there is even an error in the register function. there is an endl to many. open the file in an editer. And use a debugger or use more cout statements where you output something that shows where you are and what the value of some variables is. Do this in checkcredentials to find your problem.

Comment: It is better to read whole lines in the readcredentials. and do a little parsing to get the user and password. Not sure what your code does with the endl.

Comment: okk I'll troubleshoot first, thanks for the push